# CSS Custom Button

Tags: css

I am making my custom curved button. But I am facing an issue, a border is not showing on the right bottom side of the button. Maybe I am doing something wrong? I need to make a button something like this!

[image]

Almost All done, But a border is not there on the right bottom side!

Here is the code!

```css
.polygon .outer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 118px;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    color: #F94141;
  border:2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 80px, 0px 50%, 0 0px, 290px 0px, 145px 50%, 63px 78px);
    clip-path: polygon(0px 80px, 0px 50%, 0 0px, 290px 0px, 145px 50%, 63px 78px);
    padding: 11px 7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<a class="button" href="#button">
  <div class="polygon border">
    <span class="outer">
      DÉCOUVRIR
    </span>
  </div>
  </a>

</body>
</html>
```

Trying to do through the clip path! 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: from my knowledge you cant do it with simple css, you can of course define border-right-bottom-radius to curve the border but you wont get exactly what you wanr. perhaps you should look into doing it with an svg/ canvas or maybe using before and after.

Comment: remove the padding and add border-width   10px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the background color of the polygon class for the border color. then position your inner block (called .outer ??) and position it absolute in your other block.

In this way you can cut out the polygon you want.

I have not completely styled it the way you want, but you will work it out with some tinkering.

PRO tip: try to use as much as percentages in the polygons as possible. it is more clearer and you will not have to completely rewrite your polygon after you want to resize it.

You could make it a scss mixing if you want it, wich will make it even more flexible (calculations for the .outer class for example)

Here a usefull tool for making clip-paths (wich will be outputted in percentages)
https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

```css
.polygon .outer {
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    color: #F94141;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 85%, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 85%, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
    padding: 11px 7px;
}
.polygon{
    position: relative;
    width: 132px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 11px 7px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 85%, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 85%, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
}
.outer{
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px; /* equal to border thickness */
  left: 2px; /* equal to border thickness */
  width: 128px; /* container height - (border thickness * 2) */
  height: 16px; /* container height - (border thickness * 2) */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<a class="button" href="#button">
  <div class="polygon border">
    <span class="outer">
      DÉCOUVRIR
    </span>
  </div>
  </a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ThankYou! But it looks little bit buggy, no worries. I will adjust them now! thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fiddle for the same maybe it will help you: https://jsfiddle.net/0xs8fecv/

i used:

```
.polygon {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 80px, 0px 50%, 0 0px, 290px 0px, 145px 50%, 63px 78px);
    clip-path: polygon(0px 80px, 0px 50%, 0 0px, 290px 0px, 145px 50%, 63px 78px);
    width: 135px;
    height: 46px;
    background: black;
}

.polygon .outer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 118px;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    color: #F94141;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(5px 83px, 4px 13%, 0 5px, 346px 4px, 141px 50%, 60px 76px);
    clip-path: polygon(5px 83px, 4px 13%, 0 5px, 346px 4px, 141px 50%, 60px 76px);
    padding: 11px 7px;
}
```

Actually, you have given the border to span which will get hidden behind the clip path so, I just give another clip-path to its parent div and with background-color

Answer (score -1):

why you included

```
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 80px, 0px 50%, 0 0px, 290px 0px, 145px 50%, 63px 78px);
        clip-path: polygon(0px 80px, 0px 50%, 0 0px, 290px 0px, 145px 50%, 63px 78px);
```

remove it, your code will work

```css
.polygon .outer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 118px;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    color: #F94141;
  border:2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
   
    padding: 11px 7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<a class="button" href="#button">
  <div class="polygon border">
    <span class="outer">
      DÉCOUVRIR
    </span>
  </div>
  </a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't read my question carefully! Am asking for a curve on right bottom side! but the border is not showing there! you see a transparent white space? i want a border there too!